# For each inside map Dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule-esb

I am trying to do a for each on a database result set in Dataweave and not able to achieve the result.

**Input payload:**

```
{
    "x_orders_cursor": [{
        "LINE_QTY": 1,
        "ORDER_NUMBER": 11820490,
        "ORDERED_ITEM": "PAT1M",
        "LINE_UOM": "PC"
    }, {
        "LINE_QTY": 5000,
        "ORDER_NUMBER": 11820542,
        "ORDERED_ITEM": "ACC62-A-D",
        "LINE_NUMBER": 1,
        "LINE_UOM": "PC"
    }, {
        "LINE_QTY": 2000,
        "ORDER_NUMBER": 11820542,
        "ORDERED_ITEM": "ACC62-A-D",
        "LINE_NUMBER": 2,
        "LINE_UOM": "PC"
    }]
}
```

**Expected Payload:**

```
{
    "Orders": [
        {
            "OrderNum": "11820490",
            "Lines": [
                {
                    "LineNum": 1,
                    "ProductNum": "PAT1M",
                    "TxnQty": 1,
                    "TxnQtyUOM": "PC"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "OrderNum": "11820542",
            "Lines": [
                {
                    "LineNum": 1,
                    "ProductNum": "ACC62-A-D",
                    "TxnQty": 1000,
                    "TxnQtyUOM": "PC"
                },
                {
                    "LineNum": 2,
                    "ProductNum": "ACC62-A-D",
                    "TxnQty": 2000,
                    "TxnQtyUOM": "PC"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Result set is based on a database table that stores both Order Number and Line Number.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`groupBy`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-operators#group-by) for grouping line numbers from same order then map it. Please refer following code

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
Orders : payload.x_orders_cursor groupBy $.ORDER_NUMBER map {
    "OrderNum": $.ORDER_NUMBER[0],
        "Lines": $ map (LineDetails,index) ->{
            "LineNum": LineDetails.LINE_NUMBER default 1,
            "ProductNum": LineDetails.ORDERED_ITEM,
            "TxnQty": LineDetails.LINE_QTY,
            "TxnQtyUOM": LineDetails.LINE_UOM
        } orderBy $.LineNum
} orderBy $.OrderNum
```

I have used [`orderBy`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-operators#order-by) for ordering order and line items with order number and line numbers respectively

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the map and groupby operators to do this. Should be on below lines

```
payload groupBy $.ORDER_NUMBER map {
OrderNum: $.ORDER_NUMBER[0],
Lines": $ map (val,index) -> {
            LineNum: val.LINE_NUMBER default 1,
            ProductNum: val.ORDERED_ITEM,
            TxnQty: val.LINE_QTY,
            TxnQtyUOM: val.LINE_UOM
        } orderBy $.LineNum
} orderBy $.OrderNum
```